# Complexity of Gaussian Process algorithms is $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$

Tags: probability, algorithms, regression, machine-learning, neural-networks

It is often quoted that the complexity of Gaussian Process algorithms is $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ due to the need to invert an $n \times n$ matrix, where $n$ is the number of data points. But as far as I can find online, matrix multiplication is also $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$.

So would the complexity of GP algorithms still be $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ if we no longer needed to invert matrices? Or have I missed something.

Comment: (it's called the [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination)) and yes solving a linear system or inverting a matrix is the same algorithm, but in the case of matrix inversion you solve $n$ linear systems at a time (you solve for the $n$ basis vectors)

Comment: I don't see how this is answering my question. I am fine with the fact that a matrix inversion will scale as $n^3$, what I'm confused about is the fact that if matrix multiplication is also scaling as $n^3$ then why is it matrix inversion that is always said to be the reason GPs scale so badly.

Comment: I didn't see your matrix multiplication sentence. [wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra)

Comment: This link is where I looked and it backs up what I'm asking since both multiplication and inversion seems to have the same levels of complexity in the various algorithms. So why is inversion always put forward as the cause of high complexity?

Comment: EHHH, Gaussian elimination is an $O(n^3)$ algorithm, however it does **not** make use of matrix product. To solve a linear system $Au=v$, you *may* first inverse the matrix (also with Gaussian elimination, but in a slightly different way as you solve $n$ systems instead of a single one, still in $O(n^3)$) and compute afterwards $u=A^{-1}v$, but then this last matrix-vector product is $O(n^2)$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I know gaussian elimination doesn't make use of a matrix product, however in GP we do use matrix products as well as inversion (to define derivative of log-likelihood) and so it is still a factor.

Comment: @EHH When you say it is $O(n^3)$ due to the need to invert a matrix, do you mean $\Omega(n^3)$? If you have to do a difficult task, that provides a lower bound on the complexity, not an upper bound. And I don't understand your uses of "But" and "So". I just don't understand the logic of your question. Can you rephrase it or explain it to me?

Comment: Does anyone know a good academic reference on the complexity of Gaussian process regression?

Answer (score 5):

Matrix multiplications is indeed of complexity $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ (well, for school book implementations). It is cubic when we multiply two matrices together. However, in my personal opinion, it is quite rare to perform this operation in machine learning algorithms, hence perhaps that is why we rarely hear people blaming the complexity of algorihms on matrix multiplication.

A more common operation is to perform matrix-vector multiplication, which has complexity $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$. In contrast, computing $A^{-1}$ alone would cost us $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$.

If you no longer need to invert the matrix, the final complexity would depends on what do you replace this step with. The complexity stays the same if you replace this step with another $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ procedure. If you replace it with a cheaper procedure, then the complexity reduces.

Comment: The complexity wouldn't necessarily reduce, as matrix products are needed for the derivative and hessians of the log-likelihood so even without inversion we always have matrix products and so I think it would stay as $n^3$.